# How to make HTTPS request in java

Tags: java, api, http, https, apache-nifi

I am trying to fetch data from api which use https protocol,
but the problem is, I dont know how java work with https, what are the steps the one should follow.
My Program is working correctly on http but i need to convert this into https.
here is my current code ->

```
 var url = "https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/lists/all/contacts/all";
 String authorizationHeader = "Bearer " + context.getProperty(token).getValue();
 var client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
boolean whichOne = currentTimeUTC.isBefore(expireIn);
 if (whichOne) {
  var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().GET().header("Authorization", authorizationHeader)
          .header("Content-Type", "application/json").uri(URI.create(url)).build();
try {
   var response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
   flowFile = session.write(flowFile, (rawIn, rawOut) -> {
       try(final InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(rawIn);
            final OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(rawOut)) {
                out.write(response.body().getBytes());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error -> "+e);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

can any one help me...

Comment: Have you simply tried that `url` with `https://`?

Comment: What error do you get with that https url?

Comment: Try looking at [Java HttpsURLConnection example](https://mkyong.com/java/java-https-client-httpsurlconnection-example/).